# Clean Genymotion virtual devices local cache

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

How can I clean the virtual devices local cache of Genymotion?

When I try to add a virtual device "Galaxy S4 / HTC One / Xperia Z - 4.2.2 - with Google Apps - API 17 - 1080x1920" in the "Virtual Device Deployment" dialog I get the warning:

"This virtual device is deprecated. It is recommanded that you remove it from your local cache and that you use a newer version"

My current version of Genymotion is 2.2.0 and the virtual device was created using Genymotion 1.3.0.
VirtualBox versions is 4.3.10 r93012.
I'm on Mac OS X Mavericks 10.9.2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open Genymotion, go to Settings and then navigate to the "Misc" (Miscellaneous) tab, and click on `Clear cache`

[image]

Also, go to `~\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion` and remove the (old device) files in the deployed, ova and templates directories.