# Android SQLite Create table statement

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, oncreate, create-table

I have a problem where this table is not being created at all in android.
Here is the whole MyDBHandler:

```
package com.example.plrardiakao;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MudeDB.db";
    public static final String TABLE_ITEMS = "Items";

    //helper for types
    public static final String VARCHAR_TYPE = " VARCHAR(50)";
    public static final String BOOL_TYPE = " BOOLEAN";
    public static final String INT_TYPE = " INTEGER";

    //helper for column names
    public static final String COLUMN_ENTRY_ID = "id"; //integer
    public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "itemtitle"; //varchar(50)
    public static final String COLUMN_AUTHOR = "author"; //varchar(50)
    public static final String COLUMN_CATEGORY = "category"; //varchar(50)
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date"; //int
    public static final String COLUMN_TYPE = "type"; //varchar(50)
    public static final String COLUMN_COUNTRY = "country"; //varchar(50)
    public static final String COLUMN_COLOUR = "colour"; //varchar(50)
    public static final String COLUMN_MATERIAL = "material"; //varchar(50)
    public static final String COLUMN_FAVOURITE = "is_favourite"; //boolean
    public static final String COLUMN_IMGRES = "imgres"; //varchar(50)
    public static final String COLUMN_NUMBER_OF_PICS = "nr_of_pics"; // integer

    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, 
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEMS + 
                "("
                     + COLUMN_ENTRY_ID      + INT_TYPE +" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," 
                     + COLUMN_TITLE         + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                     + COLUMN_AUTHOR        + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                     + COLUMN_CATEGORY      + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                     + COLUMN_DATE          + INT_TYPE      + ","
                     + COLUMN_TYPE          + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                     + COLUMN_COUNTRY       + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                     + COLUMN_COLOUR        + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                     + COLUMN_MATERIAL      + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                     + COLUMN_FAVOURITE     + BOOL_TYPE     + ","
                     + COLUMN_IMGRES        + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                     + COLUMN_NUMBER_OF_PICS + INT_TYPE + 
                ")";
          db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE);
    }
    //CREATE TABLE Items(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, itemtitle VARCHAR(50),author)
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEMS);
          onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addItem(Item item) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, item.getItemTitle());
        values.put(COLUMN_AUTHOR, item.getAuthor());
        values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORY, item.getCategory());
        values.put(COLUMN_DATE, item.getDate());
        values.put(COLUMN_TYPE, item.getType());
        values.put(COLUMN_COUNTRY, item.getCountry());
        values.put(COLUMN_COLOUR, item.getColour());
        values.put(COLUMN_MATERIAL, item.getMaterial());
        values.put(COLUMN_FAVOURITE, item.getFavourite());
        values.put(COLUMN_IMGRES, item.getImgres());
        values.put(COLUMN_NUMBER_OF_PICS, item.getNumberOfPics());

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.insert(TABLE_ITEMS, null, values);
        db.close();

    }

    public int findPictureNumber(String itemtitle) {
        String query = "SELECT nr_of_pics FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS + " WHERE " +COLUMN_TITLE + "=" + "'"+itemtitle+"'" ;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);


        int PicsNumber=0;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            PicsNumber=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
            cursor.close();
            return PicsNumber;
        } else {
            //wtf?
        }
            db.close();
            return 0;
    }

    public void changeFavourite(String itemtitle, boolean isFavourite)
    {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String strSQL = "UPDATE "+TABLE_ITEMS+" SET "+COLUMN_FAVOURITE +"="+ isFavourite +" WHERE columnId = "+ "'"+itemtitle+"'";

        db.execSQL(strSQL);

    }

    public String AuthorName(String itemtitle) {
        String query = "SELECT " +COLUMN_AUTHOR+ " FROM " + TABLE_ITEMS + " WHERE " +COLUMN_TITLE + "=" + "'"+itemtitle+"'" ;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

        String authorname="error1";

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            authorname=cursor.getString(0);
            cursor.close();
        } else {
            //wtf?
        }
            db.close();
        return authorname;
    }

}
```

There is an error, probably somewhere in Create_table, but I have no idea where. I know that the table is not created, previous placeholder table is there, and upon execution it shows error that some of the columns don;'t exist. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you didn't post the error? Can you post it? Also if you did changes in the db table then you have to increase the db version

Comment: DB Version! That was that! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Goto App manager of your android phone. Delete all the data related to your app. Then try to run your app agian. And also in your `CREATE TABLE` statement you need spaces between your column names and column types.

Comment: I do it on a Virtual Machine from Genymotion. How to do it there?
I have spaces in helper strings already.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835372/clean-genymotion-virtual-devices-local-cache

Comment: Thanks, it was the DB Version. Thank you so much anyways for taking your time.